# activate ModalPopupExtender witheout giving it TargetControlID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

how can i activate a ModalPopupExtender,
whiteout giving the TargetControlID a button id in the aspx page (i dont know wiche button will activate the ModalPopupExtender i have a multiple buttons on my page)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have one TargetControlID but you can hide it and activate the pop up with a different button:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbPrivacy" Text="PRIVACY"/>
    </div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MpePrivacy" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbPrivacy"

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbPrivacy2" Font-Underline="true" 
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btMpePrivacy_Click">Privacy</asp:LinkButton>

protected void btMpePrivacy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalPop = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)(this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("MpePrivacy")));
    modalPop.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: you can use Hidden field as a TargetControlID:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="btnTrigger" runat="server" />
```

and as for showing the popup, in each button onclick event:

```
(IdOfModalPopupExtender).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ModalPopupExtender_xyz.Show();
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's question.